# How do you dplyr summarise_at all columns in R?

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a data frame with a column 'freq' and several other integer columns. The number of integer columns I have will vary each time the code is run, so I'm looking for syntax that will summarise all of the columns except for freq, which is grouped. If there is something in dplyr syntax that would be great!

This code negates the first column after 'freq' rather than provides all columns

```
event_data_consumer_1 <- event_data_consumer %>% 
  group_by(freq) %>% 
  summarise_at(-c(1), mean, na.rm = TRUE)
```

Comment: summarise(across(everything(), mean, na.rm = TRUE))

Comment: There is  `summarise_all(mean, na.rm = TRUE)`, though this is superseded by the solution @Jonathan provided above

Comment: this approach will create a problem if a character column appears in data

Answer (score 0):

I intentionally changed the function you asked (mean to sum) so you could
ensure there is no aggregated function applied to the grouping variable

```
tibble(freq=c(1,1,2), let=letters[1:3], a=1:3, b=1:3 * 10) %>% 
    print() %>%
    group_by(freq) %>% 
    summarise(across(where(is.numeric), sum, na.rm=T)) %>%
    print()

# A tibble: 3 x 4
   freq let       a     b
  <dbl> <chr> <int> <dbl>
1     1 a         1    10
2     1 b         2    20
3     2 c         3    30

# A tibble: 2 x 3
   freq     a     b
  <dbl> <int> <dbl>
1     1     3    30
2     2     3    30
```